# Is there a way to use two (or more) event parameters in Vue with v-on (@)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I was wondering if there is a way to use two event parameters with v-on (@).

Ex:

```
<div @click:mouseover="someFunction"></div>
```

Instead of writing:

```
<div @click="someFunction" @mouseover="someFunction"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible, each event is handled separately, but there's another syntax which handle the events with object syntax :

```html
<div @="{click:someFunction, mouseover:someFunction}"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, each event should be specified one way or another.

You could bind them via an object if you want less bloat in your template.

psudo code:

```js
<template>
  <div v-on="handlers" />
</template>

<script>
...
data() {
  return {
    handlers: {
      'click': func,
      'mouseover': func,
       ...
    }
  }
}
...
</script>
```

Comment: It's `mouseover`, lower case.